# what is assertion error with eigen meaning?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, eigen

When I compute generalized eigen,I write this following code ,and the part of code :

```
Eigen::MatrixXcf get_Generalized_eigen(const Eigen::MatrixXf &A, const Eigen::MatrixXf &B){
    Eigen::GeneralizedEigenSolver<Eigen::MatrixXf> ges; 
    ges.compute(A, B);
    // cout << "The (complex) generalzied eigenvalues are (alphas./beta): " << ges.eigenvalues().transpose() << endl;
    cout << ges.eigenvalues().transpose(); 
}
```

and my err:

```
distance_matrix: /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Eigenvalues/GeneralizedEigenSolver.h:204: Eigen::GeneralizedEigenSolver<_MatrixType>::EigenvalueType Eigen::GeneralizedEigenSolver<_MatrixType>::eigenvalues() const [with _MatrixType = Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1>; Eigen::GeneralizedEigenSolver<_MatrixType>::EigenvalueType = Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_quotient_op<std::complex<float>, float>, Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<float>, -1, 1>, Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, 1> >]: Assertion `m_valuesOkay && "GeneralizedEigenSolver is not initialized."' failed.
./setup.sh: line 6:  3609 Aborted                 ./distance_matrix
```

can anyone help me ? thank a lot!

i am expecting to know why it happen and how to fix it.

Comment: I'd guess you didn't initialize the solver. The assertion is basically just a runtime check to make sure you're using things properly.

Comment: Looking at the source code of `GeneralizedEigenSolver`, apparently some QZ decomposition does not converge within 400 iterations. In this case, `GeneralizedEigenSolver::compute()` fails. So, I guess your input matrices do not allow to compute the generalized eigenvalues. What are your input matrices? Also, are you using the latest version of Eigen?

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the entry to the function, then inspect the backtrace when the program hits the assertion. This usually lets you find the real cause of the problem.

Comment: BTW The bug that causes this unhelpful assertion [has been fixed already](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/merge_requests/1045), no need to file a bug report. In future versions you can check whether the computation succeeded by calling ```ges.info()```